# Laravel- VueJS image upload

Tags: javascript, vue.js, file-upload, image-uploading

I need Vuejs image upload. Backend is Laravel. But images not sending in Controller.

```
 <form method="POST" class="form-horizontal" role="form"  v-on:submit.prevent="updateProduct(editProduct.id)"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Answer (score 0):

In your input file use`@change="sync`

In vue create funcion

```
sync: function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        this.newProducts.product_images = e.target.files;
        console.log(this.newProducts.product_images);
    },
```

I think it can help you! It will console all files you have!